# Automount a samba share using fstab cifs in a debian virtualbox

Tags: debian, mount, cifs, fstab, automount

When i run:

```
mount -a
```

as root user in my virtualbox machine i will get the samba share mounted, so my settings in my /etc/fstab are working:

```
//192.168.0.99/download /vagrant/Downloads cifs credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,auto 0 0
```

But why is this share not automounted when my virtualbox machine is booting?
I run virtualbox in headless mode using vagrant. At the moment i need to run this sequence:

```
vagrant up
vagrant ssh
sudo su
mount -a
```

While this should be enough:

```
vagrant up
```

I am new to debian administration. Is there a log file for fstab / mount issues, that can be viewed after booting? Could it be a timeout or dependency issue on booting? How to debug it best?

Answer (score 3):

The network might not yet be initialized at this point. You can add `_netdev` to the mount options. This will delay the mount until the network is connected.

```
//192.168.0.99/download /vagrant/Downloads cifs credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,_netdev,auto 0 0
```

Comment: The root cause was a different issue. But pointing out _netdev makes sense, too. Thanks. You got an up-vote.

Answer (score 2):

The mount point target:

```
/vagrant
```

and

```
/vagrant/Downloads
```

is itself not available at booting time. /vagrant is a mount point itself, which is introduced by vagrant tool right after the virtual machine boot finished.

Changing fstab to:

```
//192.168.0.99/download /mnt/Downloads cifs credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,auto,_netdev 0 0
```

did the trick of mounting it at boot time.